# How many parallel requests can one Google App Engine Python instance handle?

Tags: google-app-engine

How many threads/requests can one Google App Engine Python instance handle in parallel? I'm using python27 runtime and threadsafe option is enabled (true). 
Are there any restictions or conditions which could limit parallelism?

For clarification: this isn't about Java or Python GAE SDK.

Comment: A (little) bit related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105564/can-google-app-engine-be-used-for-massively-parallel-computation

Answer (score 8):

The amount of parallelism you get is highly dependent on the workload of your application. If your requests are CPU bound, you'll only serve one request at a time. On the other hand, if your requests are RPC bound, you could potentially serve 10's of concurrent requests. However, there are two relavent limits:

1. Instance size. The default 600MHz F1 instance can only serve so many concurrent requests before hitting the CPU limit, overloading your instance and causing a significant increase in latency.

2. There is a hard limit on concurrent requests. It's implementation dependent and subject to change, but at this moment on python27, it's 8.

Answer (score 1):

Although I get millions of hits/day my QPS is around 2 and my requests are under a second

So don't expect too much parallelism its 2-3 at most

( It's impossible to determine a QPS value for your use-case, this is my use-case )