# What is the maximum computational throughput gain on Azure?

Tags: google-app-engine, azure

What is the maximum computational throughput gain on Azure?

On Google App Engine, in March 2011, the answer was determined by testing to be 43.  What is the equivalent number for Azure?

[Test results to measure computational throughput gain on Google App Engine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105564/can-google-app-engine-be-used-for-massively-parallel-computation)

**Edit** I have received a comment that the throughput gain of GAE cannot reasonably be compared to Azure.  If it is compute bound and entirely parallelizable, I don't see why not.  Imagine the application is to count to a large integer `x` trillion. Have each of `n` threads count to `x/n` trillion.  `n` GAE threads does not result in `1/n`th the elapsed time of one thread and it varies with how you might do it.  The reciprocal is a measure of throughput gain and the maximum I achieved on GAE was 43.

43x is woefully short of, say, 1000x at which point I would consider porting my code to GAE. This is a feasibility study; far from pointless.  I believe I have included enough information at the link for anybody to write an essentially identical test program. (Sorry, if that's obvious.)

Answer (score 2):

Since March 2011, when your GAE testing was concluded, GAE has gotten [backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview), where you can choose [different instance types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Instance_Classes).

Also, with GAE 1.6.4 there are now [threads on backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#background_threads), to help you better utilize multi-core instances.

So I believe your computational throughput test should be repeated using these new features.

Comment: Interesting.  On offer is a 4.8 GHz instance but there are no Intel chips running at 4.8 GHz on this list.  http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html

Comment: AFAIK this is a multicore cpu where speed is sum of all core speeds.

Comment: The test is fairly pointless anyway - the 'gain' depends on many things, including what sort of work you're doing, how you're doing it, and what the settings of your app are. There's no theoretical limit on how much processing power you can use on App Engine - it's up to you.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, You're wrong about this being pointless. I am explicit about the work: computation. That implies computation unconstrained by I/O, cache, and registers. Real work is constrained but knowing the unconstrained gain can make or break the feasibility of Azure of GAE for a particular app. The point of the question is, in part, to determine the settings or if there are no settings that give 1000 fold gain. There is no theoretical limit but this is not a theoretical question. It is a question about a specific problem on a specific systems with what ever settings are most favourable

Comment: @broiyan It's pointless for two reasons: First, App Engine isn't really built with arbitrary bulk computation in mind - it's built to serve highly scalable webapps. Second, the number you're measuring is effectively meaningless, because your result depends on a large number of variables, including what you're doing, how you're doing it, if you have billing enabled, and how much of your work is parallelizable. You can't simply run a test like this and publish a number and expect that to be in anyway comparable across services.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, I thought it was obvious that the application is virtually entirely parallelizable and compute constrained. It's obvious on the page of the link. Your assertion doesn't make sense to me: gain should be comparable for a pure computation problem. I think you are having trouble imagining the application so just take the trivial case of counting to a large integer.

Comment: @broiyan My point is that 'gain' is a meaningless figure. You're effectively asking "what's the most work I can do in parallel on this infrastructure", and dividing that by the work you can do on a single machine, but on pretty much every cloud computing infrastructure - including App Engine - the amount of work you can do isn't fixed: we support customers of pretty much any size at all.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, When you say you support customers of any size you are implying that higher throughput can be achieved but I see that on the other thread you are short of specifics on how to fix the problem.

Comment: @broiyan: You can run any number of dedicated backend instances and this will scale if your computational problem does not greatly depend on fast exchange of data between instances. Most computational clusters excel at this - they have a dedicated high-speed low-latency network especially for this purpose. OTOH web-oriented cloud systems (GAE, EC2, Azure) were not build for this purpose and do not excel at this.

Comment: @Peter Knego, this is a Azure/GAE question so are you saying there is a way to get dedicated backend instances on Azure and GAE? I would guess not.

Comment: I don't know about Azure, but yes on GAE there are dedicated backend instances. Did you even read my answer?

Comment: I'm wary of more dead-ends but I will have a closer look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest evaluating Go or Python (the 2.7 runtime supports NumPy, which has carefully optimized code inside it) in addition to Java under the newest runtime, as well as using the backends Peter mentioned. In any case, I don't think either App Engine or Azure are the best choices for HPC. You'd get much higher throughput on numeric workloads on Amazon's GPU-enabled instances (cg1.4large), provided your code is capable of exploiting that (if it's not, I advise you to make it capable, as GPUs are much cheaper than CPUs in numeric workloads).

Answer (score 0):

A 2013 update about this matter,
in the end of 2012, Microsoft announced big data support:
http://www.hpcinthecloud.com/hpccloud/2012-11-13/microsoft_azure_outfits_cloud_for_big_compute.html

it is now available on http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/big-data/

this is the getting started article: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/get-started-hdinsight/?fb=nl-nl

the hdinsight is in the preview program at the moment.

> HDInsight is Microsoft's Hadoop-based service that brings a 100% Apache Hadoop-based solution to the cloud. HDInsight gives you the ability to gain the full value of Big Data with a modern, cloud-based data platform that manages data of any type, whether structured or unstructured, and of any size. With HDInsight you can seamlessly store and process data of all types through Microsoft's modern data platform that provides simplicity, ease of management, and an open Enterprise-ready Hadoop service all running in the cloud. You can analyze your Hadoop data directly in Excel, using new capabilities like PowerPivot and Power View.

I cannot find anything about the maximum throughput. You might have to port your code and test it yourself.